# Список по данным из JSON-файла

Tags: javascript, json, dom

Нужен обычный список "select" который бы заполнился данными из json-файла по полю value

```
var json = [
  {"value":"2","data":"2019-03-10 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"2","data":"2019-03-11 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:29"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:30"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:40"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:45"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:01"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:10"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:22"}
];
```

Как сделать чтобы был select по value

Comment: что значит _перенести в html с помошью DOM js_? что значит _был select по value_?

Comment: нужен обычный список select который бы заполнился данными из json по полю value

Comment: вы либо мысль свою ясно выразите, чтобы все окружающие понять могли, что вы хотите. либо приведите результат html-кода который вы хотите получить. Второе предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не `json`, а **массив объектов**! `${item.data}` вывел для наглядности.

```js
let options, json = [
  {"value":"2","data":"2019-03-10 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"2","data":"2019-03-11 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:29"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:30"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:40"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:45"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:01"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:10"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:22"}
],
select = document.getElementById('json-select');

json.forEach(function(item) {
 options += `<option value="${item.value}">${item.data}</option>`;
});

select.innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<p>Ваш выбор</p>
<select id="json-select">
</select>
```